# How to display or hide letters in a string - Hangman game

Tags: c#

I'm a newbie in C# and I'm learning it for the past few weeks basically doing tasks and challenges to improve my knowledge. I came across making a "Hangman" console app and I'm close to finishing it. In fact, I can say that I made it but I would like to improve something and learn one new thing.

This is an example of my question if you can't understand it, sorry, English is not my main language.
You know how when you play hangman, once you guess the right letter that letter "shows itself" on its position in a word.

```
etc. word Head

you guess "e" and it prints _e__
you guess "d" and it prints _e_d
you guess "H" and it prints He_d
you guess "a" and it prints Head
```

Here is my code :

```
using System;

namespace Hangman
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random random = new Random();

            string word1;
            Console.Write("Please enter a random word: ");
            word1 = Console.ReadLine();
            word1.ToLower();
            Console.Clear();

            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            do
            {
                string guess;
                Console.Write("Please enter a letter: ");
                guess = Console.ReadLine();

                if (guess == "" +
                    "")
                {
                    i += 1;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Not allowed. You have {word1.Length - i} tries left.\n");
                    
                }


                else if(word1.Contains(guess) == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You guessed correctly !\n");
                    j += 1;
                }

                else
                {
                    i += 1;
                    Console.WriteLine($"You guessed wrongly ! You have {word1.Length - i} tries left\n");
                    
                }

                /* If you guessed all the letters correctly this will print that you won */
                if (j == word1.Length)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine($"You won ! The guessing word was {word1}.\n");
                }
                /* If you tried too many times it will end your program and you will lose.
                 * If you guessed all letters in a word correctly you win and the game is done. */

                if(i == word1.Length)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine($"You lost ! The guessing word was {word1}.\n");
                }

            } while (i != word1.Length & j != word1.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [position cursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setcursorposition?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: I really don't see a way to do this with the method that you posted. Could you explain a bit?

Comment: You can print a character at a specified position, which is what your question title asked for, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few flows with your code, bugs if you will -

If you enter the word `head` and you keep guessing `h` you win.

When you enter your guess you can actually enter a string not just a single character.

Also the code does not consider the possibility for multiple character entries. For example if the word is `alexleo` - and I guess `l` - it will only give me a single match.

What we have to do is keeping track of the status of each letter in the word - that is whether the letter has been guessed or not.

At each iteration:

1. The user guesses a letter -
2. If the letter is contained in the word - we change the status to
   guessed.
3. If the letter has already been guessed we warn the user.
4. If the letter is not contained in the word -we increase our flag
   `totalGuessCounts` by 1.
5. We feedback the user and display what has been guessed so far.

The loop completes when we either win or the user has run out of guesses.

Firstly I have defined my letter setting class

```
public class LetterSetting
{
    public char Letter { get; set; }
    public bool HasBeenGuessed { get; set; }

    public LetterSetting(char letter, bool hasBeenGuessed)
    {
        this.Letter = letter;
        this.HasBeenGuessed = hasBeenGuessed;
    }
}
```

Then I have defined the hangman word class - here is where we keep track of the letter that have been guessed, the logic to see if we have won and the display of what we have so far.

```
   static class HangmanWord
    {
        static List<LetterSetting> LettersStatus = new List<LetterSetting>();

        public static void Initialise(string word)
        {
            foreach (char letter in word)
            {
                LettersStatus.Add(new LetterSetting(letter, false));
            }
        }

        public static bool SetGuessStatus(char letter)
        {
            List<LetterSetting> tempLettersStatus = new List<LetterSetting>();

            foreach (LetterSetting item in LettersStatus)
            {
                if (item.Letter == letter && item.HasBeenGuessed)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                tempLettersStatus.Add(item.Letter == letter ? new LetterSetting(letter, true) : item);
            }

            LettersStatus = tempLettersStatus;

            return true;
        }

        public static void Display()
        {
            StringBuilder hangManWord = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var item in LettersStatus)
            {
                hangManWord.Append(!item.HasBeenGuessed ? '_' : item.Letter);
            }
            Console.SetCursorPosition(50, 1);
            Console.Write(hangManWord.ToString());
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0,1);
        }

        public static bool HaveWeWon()
        {
            return !LettersStatus.Any(letter => letter.HasBeenGuessed == false);
        }
    }
```

You main class will simply encapsulate the to retrieve the word and the game-loop:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int totalGuessCounts = 0;
            int maxNumberOfGuess = 0;

            Console.Write("Please enter a random word: ");
            string word = Console.ReadLine()?.ToLower();

            while (word != null && word.Contains(" ") || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(word))
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Word must not contain spaces or be nothing ");
                Console.Write("Please enter a random word: ");
                word = Console.ReadLine()?.ToLower();
            }

            maxNumberOfGuess = word.Length;

            HangmanWord.Initialise(word);
            Console.Clear();

            HangmanWord.Display();

            do
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter a letter: ");
                char guess = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                Console.Clear();

                if (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(guess))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (word.Contains(guess))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(HangmanWord.SetGuessStatus(guess)
                        ? "You guessed correctly!"
                        : "You already guessed that letter.");
                }

                else
                {
                    totalGuessCounts++;
                    Console.WriteLine($"You guessed wrongly ! You have {word.Length - totalGuessCounts} tries left\n");
                }

                if (HangmanWord.HaveWeWon())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"You won ! The guessing word was {word}.\n");
                    break;
                }

                if (totalGuessCounts == maxNumberOfGuess)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"You lost ! The guessing word was {word}.\n");
                }

                HangmanWord.Display();

            } while (totalGuessCounts != word.Length);
        }
    }
```

Here are a couple of results:
[image]
[image]

you can change the feedback layout - to your like - add a dictionary of words so you dont have to enter the word yourself - draw the hangman whilst the user guesses - Ideally you might want to move all the logic within the class HangmanWord - that is for failure , success and full feedback.

Comment: Thank you ! All this new code is a bit too much for me to understand but I'll try to understand what it does and how it works.

Comment: Ok no probs - here is the console app all together might help you understand - https://codeshare.io/5Mrrwn    if you need more info let me know.

Comment: forgot to mentioned codeshare.io/5Mrrwn  expires in 24 hr

Answer (score 0):

I coded something like this. This is my suggestion for solving this problem, but remember that it probably isn't the best. You can try to optimize it.

```
bool[] guessed = new bool[wordToGuess.Length];
int index = 0;
while ((index = wordToGuess.IndexOf(guess, index, wordToGuess.Length - index)) != -1)
{
    guessed[index] = true;
    index++;
}

for(int i = 0; i < wordToGuess.Length; i++)
{
    if(guessed[i])
        Console.Write(wordToGuess[i]);
    else
        Console.Write('_');
}
```

I used [String.IndexOf(String, Int32, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netcore-3.1) method for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to optimize for myself but it doesn't work for me.